# RoR: not able to connect paperclip to Amazon S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I have decided to deploy my app to Heroku and I was following their tutorials. However, Im trying to connect to my Amazon S3 bucket with a paperclip plugin right now and Im getting this error:

> ArgumentError in Images#index
>
> Showing app/views/images/index.html.erb where line #19 raised:
>
> syntax error on line 0, col 39: `bucket: (MY BUCKET HERE)
>   access_key_id: (MY ACCESS KEY ID HERE)
>   secret_access_key: (MY SECRET ACCESS KEY HERE)
>   '
>   Extracted source (around line #19):
>
> 16:     <%=h image.created_at %>
>   17:     <%=h image.updated_at %>
>   18:     
>   19: <% if image.img.exists? then %>
>   20:
>
> <%= image_tag image.img.url(:thumb) %>
>
> 21: <% else %>
>   22:
>
> There are no photo's attached, upload one.
>
> RAILS_ROOT: C:/Users/Mariusz/Sites/wiw_development
>
> Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
>   C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb:133:in `load'
>
>   C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb:133:in`load'
>   C:/Users/Mariusz/Sites/wiw_development/vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip/storage.rb:236:in `find_credentials'
>
>   C:/Users/Mariusz/Sites/wiw_development/vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip/storage.rb:176:in`parse_credentials'
>   C:/Users/Mariusz/Sites/wiw_development/vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip/storage.rb:138:in `extended'
>
>   C:/Users/Mariusz/Sites/wiw_development/vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip/storage.rb:137:in`instance_eval'
>   C:/Users/Mariusz/Sites/wiw_development/vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip/storage.rb:137:in `extended'
>
>   C:/Users/Mariusz/Sites/wiw_development/vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:269:in`extend'
>   C:/Users/Mariusz/Sites/wiw_development/vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:269:in `initialize_storage'
>
>   C:/Users/Mariusz/Sites/wiw_development/vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:51:in`initialize'
>   C:/Users/Mariusz/Sites/wiw_development/vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip.rb:326:in `new'
>
>   C:/Users/Mariusz/Sites/wiw_development/vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip.rb:326:in`attachment_for'
>   C:/Users/Mariusz/Sites/wiw_development/vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip.rb:229:in `img'
>
>   C:/Users/Mariusz/Sites/wiw_development/app/views/images/index.html.erb:19:in`_run_erb_app47views47images47index46html46erb'
>   C:/Users/Mariusz/Sites/wiw_development/app/views/images/index.html.erb:12:in `each'
>
>   C:/Users/Mariusz/Sites/wiw_development/app/views/images/index.html.erb:12:in`_run_erb_app47views47images47index46html46erb'
>   C:/Users/Mariusz/Sites/wiw_development/app/controllers/images_controller.rb:7:in `index'

My files look like this:

1) app/models/image.rb

> class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
>    has_and_belongs_to_many :pairs
>    validates_presence_of :img_file_name
>    has_attached_file :img, :styles => {:thumb=> "100x100#", :page  => "400x320>"}, :storage => :s3, :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml"
>   end

2) config/s3.yml

> bucket: (MY BUCKET HERE)
>   access_key_id: (MY ACCESS KEY ID HERE)
>   secret_access_key: (MY SECRET ACCESS KEY HERE)

How can I get it working?

Answer (score 9):

C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb:133:in load' - this is a YAML error. You probably have a badly formatted YML file.
Try this code in your script/console:

```
require 'yaml'
my_hash = YAML::load File.read("#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml")
```

Below is an example from my working config:

```
  has_attached_file :data,
  :styles => {
    :small => "100x100#",
    :medium => "400x400#",
    :large => "640x480#"
  },
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml",
  :path => ":attachment/:id/:style.:extension",
  :bucket => "xxx"
```

And the yml file:

```
development:
  access_key_id: ***
  secret_access_key: ***
```

Answer (score 0):

You were right. My 'e' text editor was saving the yaml file in a strange format with some additional characters. Everything is working right now. THANKS!

Comment: One more thing: if my answer helped you, please mark it as the answer to your question (the green check mark) :) 
10qu