# Rails direct upload to Amazon S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upload, amazon-s3

I'm looking to add functionality to my Rails app to upload files directly to Amazon S3. From my research the general consensus seems to be to use the [s3-swf-upload-plugin](https://github.com/nathancolgate/s3-swf-upload-plugin). I've setup a sample app using that gem but I can't get it to play nice with only allowing the selection of a single file. I'd also like to create a record post upload and use paperclip to create a thumbnail for which I can find little guidance.

So my questions are:

(1) am I on the right track using that gem or should I be taking another appraoch?

(2) are there any samples out there that I could use for reference?

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Chris

Comment: Keep in mind that if you host on Heroku and intend on uploading large files, they have a 30 second request timeout that will kill any large uploads.  I posted an answer below for some sample projects to upload directly to S3 which bypasses this issue.

Answer (score 24):

Try a new Gem called [CarrierWaveDirect](https://github.com/dwilkie/carrierwave_direct) it allows you to upload files direct to S3 using a html form and easily move the image processing into a background process

Comment: +1 great gem, been waiting for something like this, that will integrate into carrierwave. thanks

Comment: Many thanks for that steer dwilkie - will definitely take a look at that gem

Comment: This is great, but any examples of how to build the POST outside of Ruby, ie: iOS?

Answer (score 6):

Not sure about whether you can modify it easily to only upload one file at a time, but this gem works very well for me. It is based on one of [Ryan Bates' Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/383-uploading-to-amazon-s3):

https://github.com/waynehoover/s3_direct_upload

Comment: Yes! This gem is the best. Big thanks to Ryan Bates and the maintainer of that gem.

Answer (score 3):

Try looking into carrierwave https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave (supports s3)
Multi file uploads with carrierwave and uploadify http://blog.assimov.net/post/4306595758/multi-file-upload-with-uploadify-and-carrierwave-on

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Rails 3, please check out my sample projects:

Sample project using Rails 3, Flash and MooTools-based FancyUploader to upload directly to S3: https://github.com/iwasrobbed/Rails3-S3-Uploader-FancyUploader

Sample project using Rails 3, Flash/Silverlight/GoogleGears/BrowserPlus and jQuery-based Plupload to upload directly to S3: https://github.com/iwasrobbed/Rails3-S3-Uploader-Plupload

By the way, you can do post-processing with Paperclip using something like this blog post describes:

http://www.railstoolkit.com/posts/fancyupload-amazon-s3-uploader-with-paperclip

Answer (score 0):

I have adapted [Heroku's direct to S3 upload solution](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails) in Rails (which uses [jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) and the [aws-sdk gem](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby)) so uploads to S3 can be made remotely using ajax. I hope this is useful:

**posts_controller.rb**

```
before_action :set_s3_direct_post, only: [:index, :create]
before_action :delete_picture_from_s3, only: [:destroy]

class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    .
    .
  end

  def create
    @post = @user.posts.build(post_params)
    if @post.save
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end

  def destroy
    Post.find(params[:id]).destroy
  end

  private

    def set_s3_direct_post
      return S3_BUCKET.presigned_post(key: "uploads/#{SecureRandom.uuid}/${filename}", success_action_status: '201', acl: 'public-read')
    end    

    def delete_picture_from_s3
      key = params[:picture_url].split('amazonaws.com/')[1]
      S3_BUCKET.object(key).delete
      return true
      rescue => e
        # If anyone knows a good way to deal with a defunct file sitting in the bucket, please speak up.
        return true
    end

    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:content, :picture_url)
    end

end
```

**posts.html.erb**

```
<div class="info"      data-url="<%= @s3_direct_post.url %>"
                  data-formdata="<%= (@s3_direct_post.fields.to_json) %>"
                      data-host="<%= URI.parse(@s3_direct_post.url).host %>">
</div>
```

**The form**

```
<%= form_for(:post, url: :posts, method: :post,
              html: { class: "post_form", id: "post_form-#{post.id}" }
            ) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :content, id: "postfield-#{post.id}", class: "postText" %>
  <%= f.button( :submit, name: "Post", title: "Post" ) do %>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <% end %>
  <span class="postuploadbutton" id="postUp-<%= post.id %>" title="Add file" >
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </span>
  <span title="Cancel file" class="noticecancelupload" id="postCancel-<%= post.id %>" >
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </span>
  <%= f.file_field :picture_url, accept: 'image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png', 
               class: "notice_file_field", id: "postFile-#{post.id}" %>
<% end %>
```

**_post.html.erb**

```
<%= button_to post_path(
                      params: {
                        id: post.id,
                        picture_url: post.picture_url
                      }
                    ),
                    class: 'btn btn-default btn-xs blurme',
                    data: { confirm: "Delete post: are you sure?" },
                    method: :delete do %>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<% end %>
```

**Javascript in each _post.html.erb**

```
$(document).off('click',"#postUp-<%= post.id %>");
$(document).on('click', '#postUp-<%= post.id %>', function(e) {
  prepareUpload("#post_form-<%= post.id %>");
  $('#postFile-<%= post.id %>').trigger("click");
});

$(document).off('click',"#postCancel-<%= post.id %>");
$(document).on('click', '#postCancel-<%= post.id %>', function(e) {
  $(".appendedInput").remove(); //  $('#postFile-<% post.id %>').val(""); doesn't work for me
  $('.progBar').css('background','white').text("");
});

$(document).off('submit',"#post_form-<%= post.id %>"); // without this the form submitted multiple times in production
$(document).on('submit', '#post_form-<%= post.id %>', function(e) { // don't use $('#post_form-<%= post.id %>').submit(function() { so it doesn't bind to the #post_form (so it still works after ajax loading)
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent normal form submission
  if ( validatePostForm('<%= post.id %>') ) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url:  $(this).attr('action'),
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      dataType: 'script'
    });
    $('#postCancel-<%= post.id %>').trigger("click");
  }
});

function validatePostForm(postid) {
  if ( jQuery.isBlank($('#postfield-' + postid).val()) && jQuery.isBlank($('#postFile-' + postid).val()) ) {
    alert("Write something fascinating or add a picture.");
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

**Javascript in application.js**

```
function prepareUpload(feckid) {
  $(feckid).find("input:file").each(function(i, elem) {
    var fileInput    = $(elem);
    var progressBar  = $("<div class='progBar'></div>");
    var barContainer = $("<div class='progress'></div>").append(progressBar);
    fileInput.after(barContainer);
    var maxFS = 10 * 1024 * 1024;

    var info             = $(".info");
    var urlnumbnuts      = info.attr("data-url");
    var formdatanumbnuts = jQuery.parseJSON(info.attr("data-formdata"));
    var hostnumbnuts     = info.attr("data-host");

    var form             = $(fileInput.parents('form:first'));

    fileInput.fileupload({
      fileInput:        fileInput,
      maxFileSize:      maxFS,
      url:              urlnumbnuts,
      type:             'POST',
      autoUpload:       true,
      formData:         formdatanumbnuts,
      paramName:        'file',
      dataType:         'XML',
      replaceFileInput: false,
      add: function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
          if (file.size > maxFS) {
            alert('Alas, the file exceeds the maximum file size of 10MB.');
            form[0].reset();
            return false;
          } else {
            data.submit();
            return true;
          }
        });
      },
      progressall: function (e, data) {
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        progressBar.css('width', progress + '%')
      },
      start: function (e) {
        progressBar.
          css('background', 'orange').
          css('display', 'block').
          css('width', '0%').
          text("Preparing...");
      },
      done: function(e, data) {
        var key   = $(data.jqXHR.responseXML).find("Key").text();
        var url   = '//' + hostnumbnuts + '/' + key;
        var input = $('<input />', { type:'hidden', class:'appendedInput', 
                     name: fileInput.attr('name'), value: url });
        form.append(input);
        progressBar.
          css('background', 'green').
          text("Ready");
      },
      fail: function(e, data) {
        progressBar.
          css("background", "red").
          css("color", "black").
          text("Failed");
      }
    });
  });
} // function prepareUpload()
```

**create.js.erb**

```
$(".info").attr("data-formdata",  '<%=raw @s3_direct_post.fields.to_json   %>'); // don't use .data() to set attributes 
$(".info").attr("data-url",       "<%= @s3_direct_post.url                 %>");
$(".info").attr("data-host",      "<%= URI.parse(@s3_direct_post.url).host %>");

$('.post_form')[0].reset();
$('.postText').val('');
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery-fileupload/basic
```

**config/initializers/aws.rb**

```
Aws.config.update({
  region: 'us-east-1',
  credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'], ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']),
})
S3_BUCKET = Aws::S3::Resource.new.bucket(ENV['S3_BUCKET'])
```

***Notes:***

This solution is designed for multiple post forms on the index.html.erb page. This is why the `@s3_direct_post` information is placed inside a div of class `info` inside index.html.erb, rather than in each post form. This means there is only one `@s3_direct_post` presented on the page at any one time, irrespective of the number of forms on the page. The data inside the `@s3_direct_post` is only grabbed (with a call to `prepareUpload()`) upon clicking the file upload button. Upon submission a fresh `@s3_direct_post` is generated in the posts controller, and the information inside `.info` is updated by create.js.erb. Storing the `@s3_direct_post` data inside the form means many different instances of `@s3_direct_post` can exist at once, leading to errors with the file name generation.

You need to `:set_s3_direct_post` in both the posts controller index action (ready for the first upload) and the create action (ready for the second and subsequent uploads).

Normal form submission is prevented by `e.preventDefault();` so it can be done 'manually' with `$.ajax({`. Why not just use `remote: true` in the form? Because in Rails, file upload is done with an HTML request and page refresh even when you try to do it remotely.

Use `info.attr()` rather than `info.data()` to set and retrieve the `@s3_direct_post` attributes because info.data doesn't get updated 
(for example see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13524107/how-to-set-data-attributes-in-html-elements) question). This means you also have to manually parse the attribute into an object using `jQuery.parseJSON()` (which .data() actually does automatically).

Don't use `//= require jquery-fileupload` in application.js. This bug was a real ballache to identify (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34560719/rails-direct-to-s3-upload-using-aws-sdk-gem-and-jquery-file-upload-on-heroku)). The [original Heroku solution](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails) didn't work until I changed this.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Paperclip to upload to S3 (see [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/paperclip/master/Paperclip/Storage/S3)) and to create thumbnails, although it uploads to temporary folder first, after that image processing can be applied before uploading file to S3.

As for the examples of such configuration, there are plenty of them throughout the blogosphere and on StackOverflow, e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013599/ror-not-able-to-connect-paperclip-to-amazon-s3/2014499#2014499).

Comment: I don't think Paperclip uploads directly to S3. Paperclip, like Carrierwave uploads to the server's tmp dir for processing and then uploads the files to S3. This means, the server will take up a whole http request handler, until the upload is finished. Which in some instances, may 'freeze' the app

Comment: Well, it uploads to tmp folder first to allow image processing (e.g. resize, create appropriate thumbnails etc) before uploading to S3. As topicstarter requires image post-processing, this solution seems better than "upload raw file directly to S3 -> download it -> create thumbnails -> upload thumbnails to S3". The problem with app 'freeze' may be solved by moving upload to S3 to the background process.

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys. The other issue with paperclip's approach of uploading to the tmp folder comes when hosting on a site like Heroku as they limit the size of uploaded files.

Comment: Paperclip doesn't let you upload directly to S3, you should edit your answer

Comment: Edited an answer. Leaving it here just in case someone looks for a way to upload to S3 indirectly (via a temp folder), but somehow stumbles upon this page.