# How to upload an image to another server via HTTP post using carrierwave(Ruby On Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, carrierwave

I am trying to upload an image to another server via HTTP post using carrierwave? What I understand so far is, Carrierwave supports some known cloud storage. but, in our application, we have a separate storage system with MongoDB. In order to store any file in that server, we can use HTTP post. Now, I am trying to write a client code to upload image. Is it possible to achieve by using Carrierwave or is there any other gem available?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using CarrierWave and MongoDB, I would use the https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave-mongoid gem to connect and store directory in GridFS.

Here's a good post on uploading and retrieving an image via carrier wave and gridfs: http://hafizbadrie.wordpress.com/2011/04/14/image-upload-with-carrierwave-and-mongoid-gridfs-mongodb-in-rails-3/

Comment: Thanks Jesse, Even though the file system container is mongoDB, my client code will just talk to that storage system via http post url. so, in this context, i dont really care about which db is going to be my container.All i have to do is, to upload image via http post to another host

Answer (score -1):

you need to provide your data where there is s3 data in the tutorials:

[stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127079/rails-direct-upload-to-amazon-s3)

Comment: Thanks p0rter, but I am trying to store image into our own file storage system, not s3

Comment: i don't understand the issue...just enter your credentials where s3 credentials are...