# How to set data attributes in HTML elements

Tags: jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I have a div with an attribute `data-myval = "10"`. I want to update its value; wouldn't it change if I use `div.data('myval',20)`? Do I need to use `div.attr('data-myval','20')` only?

Am I getting confused between HTML5 and jQuery? Please advise. Thanks!

EDIT: Updated `div.data('myval')=20` to `div.data('myval',20)`, but still the HTML is not updating.

Comment: What is in `div`? A jQuery object or element?

Comment: `div.data('myval')=20` wouldn't work to store a value only because the syntax is wrong - see the answers for the correct syntax. But note that `.data()` doesn't actually update the element _attribute,_ it stores the data elsewhere.

Comment: For those who has the sense to avoid gQuery use this ->  div.dataset.myval = '20';

Answer (score 645, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div id="mydiv" data-myval="10"></div>
```

**JS**

```
var a = $('#mydiv').data('myval'); //getter

$('#mydiv').data('myval',20); //setter
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jashwant/Se5Zu/)

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

From the reference:

> jQuery itself uses the `.data()` method to save information under the names 'events' and 'handle', and also reserves any data name starting with an underscore ('_') for internal use.

It should be noted that jQuery's `data()` doesn't change the `data` attribute in HTML.

So, if you need to change the `data` attribute in HTML, you should use `.attr()` instead.

**HTML**

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="mydiv" data-myval="10"></div>
</div>
```

**​jQuery:**

```
alert($('#outer').html());   // alerts <div id="mydiv" data-myval="10"> </div>
var a = $('#mydiv').data('myval'); //getter
$('#mydiv').attr("data-myval","20"); //setter
alert($('#outer').html());   //alerts <div id="mydiv" data-myval="20"> </div>
```

See [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jashwant/Se5Zu/2/)

Comment: I dont know what consistency you need, but I would recommend to use `data()` to `get` and `set` HTML-5 data attributes.

Comment: @Jashwant might be a useful edit instead: think of a css rule like `[data-myval="10"]{ color: red; }`, it would style the tag according to value of data attribute.

Comment: .data doesn't work. .attr works. may be we can edit the answer to make it clear. it seems the first one is the solution, while it could be a little bit better exposed. i'm not sure about how to better explain, this is the reason why I don't edit the post.

Comment: @Gaucho, is it better now ?

Comment: @Gaucho .data will only work if you use newer jQuery >= 1.4.3, for older versions .attr will work.

Comment: Still here, wondering why we have both a data object and a data attribute, and wondering why they aren't kept in sync.

Comment: @brandonscript, (I may not be correct) jQuery introduced `data()`  before HTML `data-` attributes. So, it used to store data internally in objects.

Comment: >> Using the data() method to update data does not affect attributes in the DOM. To set a data-* attribute value, use attr.
https://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score 65):

## Vanilla Javascript solution

**HTML**

```
<div id="mydiv" data-myval="10"></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

- Using DOM's [`getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) property

  ```
   var brand = mydiv.getAttribute("data-myval")//returns "10"
   mydiv.setAttribute("data-myval", "20")      //changes "data-myval" to "20"
   mydiv.removeAttribute("data-myval")         //removes "data-myval" attribute entirely
  ```
- Using JavaScript's [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property

  ```
  var myval = mydiv.dataset.myval     //returns "10"
  mydiv.dataset.myval = '20'          //changes "data-myval" to "20"
  mydiv.dataset.myval = null          //removes "data-myval" attribute
  ```

Answer (score 56):

You can also use the following `attr` thing;

**HTML**

```
<div id="mydiv" data-myval="JohnCena"></div>
```

**Script**

```
 $('#mydiv').attr('data-myval', 'Undertaker'); // sets 
 $('#mydiv').attr('data-myval'); // gets
```

OR

```
$('#mydiv').data('myval'); // gets value
$('#mydiv').data('myval','John Cena'); // sets value
```

Comment: For me worked only with .attr. Is that even possible?

Comment: I am glad it worked. The .data() call is special - not only does it retrieve HTML5 data attributes it also attempts to evaluate/parse the attributes. So with an attribute like data-myval='{"hello":"world"}' when retrieved via .data() will return an Object while retrieval via .attr() will return a string.

Answer (score 36):

Please take note that jQuery `.data()` is not updated when you change html5 `data-` attributes with javascript.

If you use jQuery `.data()` to set `data-` attributes in HTML elements you better use jQuery `.data()` to read them. Otherwise there can be inconsistencies if you update the attributes dynamically. For example, see `setAttribute()`, `dataset()`, `attr()` below. Change the value, push the button several times and see the console.

```js
$("#button").on("click", function() {
  var field = document.querySelector("#textfield")

  switch ($("#method").val()) {
    case "setAttribute":
      field.setAttribute("data-customval", field.value)
      break;
    case "dataset":
      field.dataset.customval = field.value
      break;
    case "jQuerydata":
      $(field).data("customval", field.value)
      break;
    case "jQueryattr":
      $(field).attr("data-customval", field.value)
      break;
  }

  objValues = {}
  objValues['$(field).data("customval")'] = $(field).data("customval")
  objValues['$(field).attr("data-customval")'] = $(field).attr("data-customval")
  objValues['field.getAttribute("data-customval")'] = field.getAttribute("data-customval")
  objValues['field.dataset.customval'] = field.dataset.customval

  console.table([objValues])
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Example</h1>
<form>
  <input id="textfield" type="text" data-customval="initial">
  <br/>
  <input type="button" value="Set and show in console.table (F12)" id="button">
  <br/>
  <select id="method">
    <option value="setAttribute">setAttribute</option>
    <option value="dataset">dataset</option>
    <option value="jQuerydata">jQuery data</option>
    <option value="jQueryattr">jQuery attr</option>
  </select>
  <div id="results"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 17):

To keep jQuery and the DOM in sync, a simple option may be

```
$('#mydiv').data('myval',20).attr('data-myval',20);
```

Comment: `$('#mydiv').attr('data-myval',20);`
this working well

Answer (score 9):

If you're using jQuery, use `.data()`:

```
div.data('myval', 20);
```

You can store arbitrary data with `.data()`, but you're restricted to just strings when using `.attr()`.

Comment: Note that the `.data()` method does _not_ update `data-` _attributes_ - that is, the data it stores does not end up in an attribute (which is why it can store non-string values) even though it can retrieve the value from a `data-` attribute. Though I suspect the OP doesn't really need to set _attributes_ even though that's what the question asked.

Comment: @nnnnnn: I'm not too sure when that'd end up being a problem outside of looking at the `data-` attribute through Chrome's Inspector or Firebug.

Comment: I don't think it would be a problem (besides what you mentioned, or if there is other code that uses `.attr()` to retrieve the attribute). I just thought it was worth pointing out given that the OP explicitly (if perhaps mistakenly) asked about updating attributes.

Comment: @Blender this doesn't really answer my question. I want to update the HTML, but at the same time, use element.data('myval') to retrieve it as well.

Comment: @PulkitMittal: Read @nnnnnn's comments. `.data('foo', 12)` is not the same as `.attr('data-foo', '12')`. Why do you need to update the HTML?

Comment: I need to do that because the elements generated on document load have those as data-attributes, and I want to do so for the new dynamic elements as well. I know there might be not a specific need for that, but I want to keep a consistency.

Comment: @PulkitMittal: But why? If you're going to be accessing the data attributes with `data()`, there's no use in changing the DOM element like that.

Comment: I guess. hmm... Then I think I can change both, using `.attr()` and `.data()` to keep the consistency.

Comment: @PulkitMittal: I'm still not understanding why you need to do this. It's pointless.

Comment: TO KEEP THE CONSISTENCY. I told you so!

Comment: @PulkitMittal: I'm not going to argue about it. I'm just pointing out that there is no reason to do this and you're wasting your time trying.

Comment: Thanks for your input @Blender; I appreciate it. I will keep both setters, just in case any of my later Javascript uses data-attr or something.

Comment: @PulkitMittal - Note that even with `.attr()` you're not really updating "the html", you're updating the DOM. When you ask the browser to give you the "html" (whether by `.html()` or the DOM `element.innerHTML`) the browser is effectively regenerating it for you based on the state of the DOM at the time. Sort of.

Comment: @nnnnnn that's the most important part of how the `.data()` method works. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 8):

### [jQuery] .data() vs .attr() vs .extend()

The jQuery method `.data()` updates an internal object managed by jQuery through the use of the method, if I'm correct.

If you'd like to update your `data-attributes` with some spread, use --

```
$('body').attr({ 'data-test': 'text' });
```

-- otherwise, `$('body').attr('data-test', 'text');` will work just fine.

Another way you could accomplish this is using --

```
$.extend( $('body')[0].dataset, { datum: true } );
```

-- which restricts any attribute change to `HTMLElement.prototype.dataset`, *not any additional `HTMLElement.prototype.attributes`*.