# How to give the current page url to HTML element property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML element

```
<a class="toggle-tell-friend" id='share-button-1' rel="sidebar" data-id='share-content-1' data-title='<?php echo CHtml::decode($job->getTitle());?>' data-link="CURRENT URL">Friend</a>
```

How can I set the value of data-link to the current url.

Comment: Use this reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406192/get-current-url-in-javascript) is how you get url, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13524107/how-to-set-data-attributes-in-html-elements) is how you set `data` attribute

Comment: This question isn't very clear. Not stating how exactly the user wants to implement this url. Through javascript? Maybe this includes an ajax call? I would assume there's more to it since googling "get current url javascript" isn't that hard.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want it in javascript? Since you didn't put PHP in your tags, I would assume so.

In that case, you can use `window.location.href` to do it in javascript.

`document.getElementById("share-button-1").setAttribute("data-link", window.location.href);`

or in jquery:

`$('#share-button-1').attr("data-link", window.location.href);`

in case you did mean through PHP, you could use the following:
`http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]`. In this case I'd use it like this:

```
<?php
  $dataUrl = "http://".$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST].$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
 ?>
<a class="toggle-tell-friend" id='share-button-1' rel="sidebar" data-id='share-content-1' data-title='<?php echo CHtml::decode($job->getTitle());?>' data-link="$dataUrl">Friend</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this using [**location**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) interface

```
var _getCurUrl = location.href;
$("#share-button-1").attr('data-link',_getCurUrl);
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/0zk5dsm5/3/)