# How can I change the attribute data-default-file of the input file attribute with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following file input element in my code:

```
 echo "<input type='file' name='webpagefileActualFile' id='wpfActualFile' class='dropify' data-default-file='".base_url()."myfolder/valueShouldBeHere' />";
```

I was trying to change the value of the input type file with

```
$('#wpfActualFile').val(result.message.webpagefileActualFile);
```

in my javascript but I get the error Insecure operation.

So the question is: how can I append the value of the result.message.webpagefileActualFile on the end of the data-default-file attribute with jQuery?

Comment: Well, I can understand that but I am not trying to change the value, but the attribute data-default-file. I can't do even that?

Comment: @Dekel I am not trying to set the value, I find out that I can't do that. I am trying how to set the value of the attribute data-default-file

Comment: well.. this wasn't the question :) just update your question then...

Comment: I can't mark it as dup (becuase I already marked it based on your prev question), but it's a dup of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13524107/how-to-set-data-attributes-in-html-elements

Comment: You cant do because of security reasons...correct!!

Comment: To set a `data` attribute use `data()` (or `attr()`, depending on use case), not `val()`. See the question I marked as a dupe for more info

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I am looking at that now,and I am sure that it will help me to solve the issue. Thanks.