# How to pass variable value to HTML data-type

Tags: javascript, html, addthis

I have a variable declared: var fburl = data.results[0].alias;

How can I pass the var value to the HTML data-type?

Example:

```
var myurl = data.results[0].alias;

<div class="myclass" data-url="value in myurl"></div>
```

===========

Apologize not able to explain clearly as I am no expert in js.

Get meta dynamically, and pass the values to addthis meta type.
I used .attr and it works, but not for Twitter meta.

```
var mymeta = $('.addthis_inline_share_toolbox_4m3m');
        mymeta.attr('data-url', myurl);
        mymeta.attr('data-title', mytitle);
        mymeta.attr('data-description', mydesc);
        mymeta.attr('data-media', myimage);
  }
```

Comment: show your efforts here

Comment: $('.myclass').attr('data-url',myurl);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set data attributes in HTML elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13524107/how-to-set-data-attributes-in-html-elements)

Comment: This is to pass values to addthis meta-type. I have added the code in the question

Comment: i posted my comment as answer . if it's useful mark it with green tick it's useful for future user reference @emmm

Comment: @ JYoThI, I am not able to mark on anything in the comment as there is no "tick" here that I can click on.

Answer (score 0):

Get a reference to  DOM element via using various methods and you can use [`Element.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property to get/set `data-*` custom attributes

```
document.querySelector('.myclass').dataset.url = data.results[0].alias;
```