# set data-options html attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attr

I have the following HTML

```
<div id="tabPanelContainer">
    <div id="Tab1" data-options="dxItem: { title: 'Tab1' }">
        <div id="gridContainer1"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="Tab2" data-options="dxItem: { title: 'Tab2' }" >
        <div id="gridContainer2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to create this using js or jquery I have tried the following:

A.

```
var tabs = $('#tabPanelContainer').data("options","dxItem: { title:  "+tabId+" }");
$(tabs).append('<div id='+gridId+'></div>');
```

B.

```
var tabs = $('#tabPanelContainer').attr({ 'data-options': 'dxItem: { title: "+tabId+" }' });
$(tabs).append('<div id='+gridId+'></div>');
```

I have looked at multiple threads on how to do this and tried multiple things but nothing is working....

I have found this: [How to set data attributes in HTML elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13524107/how-to-set-data-attributes-in-html-elements) , and other **similar** threads but **not quite the same** or enough to figure it out.

This creates multiple grids but not the tabs. So to be clear if I create the HTML elements on the PHP file (hardcoded) then my tabs load correctly but if I try to dynamically create the tabs based on a for loop my tabs don't get created. 
[image]
[image]

Instead of

[image]
[image]

Comment: What's your question? Is the above code not working? (I know it is not, but your question is not clear)

Comment: Hello Sam thanks for your help. I added some more clarification. I also tried the code provided but it still doesn't create the tabs correctly. I also added some pictures of how the html looks when I inspect one vs the other... I appreciate you trying to help me

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the data attribute of `#tabPanelContainer` instead of each `div` element. Use this code instead:

```
var tabs = $("#tabPanelContainer"); // <div id="tabPanelContainer">
var tab = $("<div>", { id: tabId }); // <div id="Tab1">
tab.attr("data-options", "dxItem: { title: '" + tabId + "' }");
tab.append($("<div>", { id: gridId })); // <div id="gridContainer2">
$(tabs).append(tab);
```

Comment: Hello Martin I tried this but it still didn't work. It also only created the grids without the tabs... It is like it doesn't recognize the data option for the dx item. I appreciate your help.