# How to set a data-attribute on a select element using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add simple value inside `<select>` tag. How I can do it?

Below I prepared example how it should look like.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#selectList").add("data-size='12'");

});
</script>

<select class='selectpicker' data-hide-disabled='true' id='selectList'>
</select>


// expected result
<select class='selectpicker' data-hide-disabled='true' id='selectList' data-size='12'>
</select>
```

Comment: `selectList.dataset.size='12'` or `selectList.setAttribute('data-size', '12')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set data attributes in HTML elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13524107/how-to-set-data-attributes-in-html-elements)

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy using vanilla Javascript:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  selectList.dataset.size='12';
  console.log(selectList);
})
```

```html
<select class="selectpicker" data-hide-disabled="true" id="selectList"></select>
```

You can also use `selectList.setAttribute('data-size', '12')` instead.

In jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#selectList').attr('data-size', '12');
  console.log(selectList);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selectpicker" data-hide-disabled="true" id="selectList"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you can add via `prop`

```
$("#selectList").prop('data-size', '12');
```