# HTML data attribute not changing

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

I have this Html code that in the each paragraph tag has two data attributes 'data-tag' and 'data-name'. I also have two buttons, 'Show Data' and 'Set Data'.

The **Show Data** button displays the paragraph data attributes on console correctly.

When I click on **Set Data**, it should change all paragraph tags with the data attribute 'tag' to 'Complete' but it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
  // Shows data attributes in console - WORKING
  $("#showdata").click(function() {
    $("p").each(function() {
      var tag = $(this).data("tag");
      var name = $(this).data("name");
      console.log(tag);
      console.log(name);
    });
  });

  // Change data attibute 'tag' - NOT WORKING
  $("#setdata").click(function() {
    $("p").each(function() {
      $(this).data("tag", "Complete");
      console.log($(this).data("tag"));
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p data-tag="tag1" data-name="p1">Item 1</p>
<p data-tag="tag2" data-name="p2">Item 2</p>
<p data-tag="tag3" data-name="p3">Item 3</p>

<button class="button" id="showdata">Show data</button>
<button class="button" id="setdata">Set data</button>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet that will show complete when you click - your tag=setTag does not return the data of the  tag

Comment: @TJCrowder the duplicate you marked does not answer the question the OP is asking.

Comment: Feel free to delete the question if you are allowed

Comment: `var tag=$(this).data("tag", "Complete")` uses *chaining* - so returns `$(this)`.   If you click show, then set, then show again, you can see that it is setting it correctly (using the original v1 of the question, not necessarily the edit), but you're (were) simply outputting the wrong value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because in the `#setdata` click handler `tag` holds a jQuery object as you're calling the *setter* of `data()`. It does not hold the value of the data attribute.

To do that you need to call the *getter* of `data()`, as you do in the `#showdata` click handler.

Also note that you don't need the `each()` loop when setting the same `data()` value on all the `p` elements.

```js
let getData = () => {
  $("p").each(function() {
    var tag = $(this).data("tag"); // getter
    var name = $(this).data("name"); // getter
    console.log(tag, name );
  });
}

$("document").ready(function() {
  $("#showdata").click(getData);

  $("#setdata").click(function() {
    $("p").data("tag", "Complete"); // setter
    getData();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p data-tag="tag1" data-name="p1">Item 1</p>
<p data-tag="tag2" data-name="p2">Item 2</p>
<p data-tag="tag3" data-name="p3">Item 3</p>

<button class="button" id="showdata">Show data</button>
<button class="button" id="setdata">Set data</button>
```

Comment: I'd say a comment would have been enough for this question

Comment: I'd say that answering a question by editing it isn't the correct approach.

Comment: It is if the idea is to close and delete it

Comment: Especially if OP cannot delete because there are answers which are [dupes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13524107/how-to-set-data-attributes-in-html-elements) if the dupes are not 100% what you want to say, then I am sure there is another dupe that is

Comment: Comment war between two jQuery legends, interesting :).

Comment: Personally, I'd vote to close it as a typo as OP is simply outputting the wrong thing :)

Comment: @Shree haha! I mean no mal-intent to mplungjan at all, he's someone I have a lot of respect for, in fact. However IMO this question is well formed and deserving of an answer. The first two duplicates are regarding the common data/attr misunderstanding so not relevant here. The third dupe is closer as it explains the difference between the getter/setter, but still doesn't give a solution to the OP's specific case, or help them understand why they saw the output they did. Perhaps this is better discussed on meta now though, as it's quite OT.

Comment: Definitely should *not* answer/fix the question by editing the question - equally so if the intent is to close (thus delete) as it would be lost anyway.