# How to change HTML Attribude with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, darkmode

I have a `div` where is an HTML Attribute called `data-theme` inside. I want to ask how do I change the value of the Attribute called `data-theme`. For example: From: `data-theme="dark"` to `data-theme="light"`. The value is stored in a variable as a string.

My `div`:

```html
<div id="myId" data-theme="dark"></div>
```

I want to use normal JavaScript.

Comment: @MichaelHirschler that's explicitly about the [`<object>`element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13524107/how-to-set-data-attributes-in-html-elements Please see second answer for native JS.

Comment: `document.getElementById("myId").dataset.theme="light";`

Comment: @LucaKiebel you're right. Second question is a better match for this :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementById("myId").setAttribute("data-theme", "newValue")`

Comment: Elements have a specialized `dataset` object which syncs with the corresponding data-attributes. `document.getElementById("myId").dataset.theme="light";`.