# Is it possible to have multiple value-like attributes on a single html element?

Tags: html, reactjs, dom

Here's my code:

```
function Component(props) {

  const [message, setMessage] = useState({
    type: "",
    text: "",
  });

  return (
    <div>
       <select
        onChange={(ev) => {
          setMessage({ type: **CAN SOMETHING GO HERE???**, text: ev.target.value });
        }}
        required
      >
        <option value="Ask a question" **DIFFERENT ATTRIBUTE TO SET TYPE WITH???**>Question</option>
        <option value="Leave a comment">Comment</option>
        <option value="Voice a concern">Concern</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Component;
```

Is it possible to somehow have another value or something similar in my `options` so that I can set both the type and text from the same `onChange` function? I'm not sure how else to do it and I need both a type and a text for a message to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set data attributes in HTML elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13524107/how-to-set-data-attributes-in-html-elements)

Comment: no, I'm not using JQuery

Comment: look again.  there are examples of pure js solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@DCR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4398966/dcr)'s linked question notes, you can use `data-` attributes to store your data and read them with the [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property, like this:

```
function Component(props) {

  const [message, setMessage] = useState({
    type: "",
    text: "",
  });

  return (
    <div>
       <select
        onChange={(ev) => {
          let selected = ev.target[ev.target.selectedIndex];
          setMessage({ type: selected.dataset.type, text: ev.target.value });
        }}
        required
      >
        <option value="Ask a question" data-type="negative">Question</option>
        <option value="Leave a comment" data-type="positive">Comment</option>
        <option value="Voice a concern" data-type="negative">Concern</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Component;
```

You need the `ev.target[ev.target.selectedIndex]` part because `ev.target` is the `<select>` element but you need to get the selected `<option>` element from inside it.

(Since you did not say how you plan to use this `type` data, I made up an example that it will say whether the feedback is `positive` or `negative`. This is just an example.)