# Attaching field value to button data attributes

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a several `fieldsets` in `blade`, each fieldset has the same `input` and `select` fields and a  save button

```
<div class="unit_box">
<input class="form-control {{ $errors->has('target_value') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" type="text" name="target_value" id="target_value" placeholder="{{ trans('cruds.validationRule.fields.target_value') }}" value="{{ old('target_value', '') }}">

<select class="form-control {{ $errors->has('unit') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" name="unit" id="unit" required>
    <option value disabled {{ old('unit', null) === null ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ trans('global.pleaseSelect') }}</option>
    @foreach(App\Models\ValidationRule::UNIT_SELECT as $key => $label)
    <option value="{{ $key }}" {{ old('unit', 'g') === (string) $key ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $label }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

```
<button class="next action-button" type="button" name="next" data-gotostep="3" data-unit="" data-value="">Save</button>
```

How can I send the value of the input field `target_value` and the value of `unit` inside button attributes `data-unit="" data-value=""` to use them in `jQuery` function?

Comment: Set button attributes values when one of the field value changes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13524107/how-to-set-data-attributes-in-html-elements

Comment: You could listen for the input event on the input field and the change event on the select dropdown and when these events are triggered, update the data-unit and data-value attributes of the button.

Comment: But how to pass the entered value to the button attribute? Any example?

Answer (score 0):

You have to learn basics of jQuery, it's quite simple, there is a lot of example of what you want to achieve, you could do it like this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Listen for changes in the input field
    $("#target_value").on("input", function() {
        let value = $(this).val();
        $(".next").attr("data-value", value);
    });

    // Listen for changes in the select dropdown
    $("#unit").on("change", function() {
        let unit = $(this).val();
        $(".next").attr("data-unit", unit);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please provide more information about the button data attributes in case of using this script?